# What does it mean UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]

I got this error since IOS 7. It works fine in IOS 6.

I look around the web and I found this:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8233/ios-7-crash-in-collectionview

However, the solution doesn't make sense

> I figured it out. I had incorrectly used
>   CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell. Apparently I was supposed to use
>   CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell when setting up the viewcontroller.
>   That fixed the problem. iOS 6 must have been more forgiving.

Could any of you give me a hint on this bug

Symptomps:

1. Crash
2. Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
3. Works in IOS6 and not IOS 7

The code I am suspicious with is this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize sz = [BGCollectionViewCellImage defaultSize];
    return sz;
}
```

But it seems to be too ordinary.

sz is simply CGSize of 100*120

Another is this:

```
- (BGCollectionViewCellImage *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BGCollectionViewCellImage * cell = [[BGCollectionViewCellImage alloc]init];
    Image * img= self.arImages[indexPath.row];
    [cell setImg:img andIndex:indexPath.row+1];

    return cell;
}
```

Maybe I should use dequeue something like in UITableViewCell

I got another hint. If I tried to dequeue some cell, I got this:

2013-10-14 21:18:34.346 domainname[24667:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier BGCollectionViewCellImage - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Looks like I got to register something first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to register your cell using one of the relevant registration methods provided in the [UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW10)

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerClass:(Class)viewClass forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

The relevant one of these only needs to be called once per instance of a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Looks like that UICollectionView must create cell via reuse identifier.

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone hits this, another possibility is if you forget to `return cell;` at the end of the `collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Comment: @iNasir glad this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Without storyboard you need to register your cell inside viewDidLoad :

```
// Register Nib
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CollectionViewCell_XIB bundle:MAIN_BUNDLE] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCell_ID];
```

`CollectionViewCell_XIB` is the name of your cell xib

`CollectionViewCell_ID` is the identifier of your cell xib

Answer (score 0):

fwiw I had some issues converted projects from swift2 to swift3 I was using NSIndexPath some places where it needed to be IndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I did not connect the Collection View I had in code (an IBOutlet) to the Collection View in the XIB and thats when I was getting this error